# Pandas: Segregating multiple time formats from date column

Tags: python, pandas

Input df

```
Date        Value
1999        2287        
2000        9825
2001        3897
.           3267
.           3627
.           3867
            3687
1999 Q1     3627
1999 Q2     3627
1999 Q3     3667
.           3682
.           3267
.           3067
1999 JAN    3674
1999 FEB    3657
1999 MAR    3687
```

How to segregate different formats in `Date` column in different dataframes?

Output

df1

```
Date        Value
1999        2287        
2000        9825
2001        3897
.
.
.
```

df2

```
Date        Value
1999 Q1     3627
1999 Q2     3627
1999 Q3     3667
.
.
.
```

df3

```
Date        Value
1999 JAN    3674
1999 FEB    3657
1999 MAR    3687
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('str')
df1 = df[df['Date'].str.len() == 4]
df2 = df[df['Date'].str.len() == 7]
df3 = df[df['Date'].str.len() == 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on **Juypiter Notebooks**.
You can use `df.loc[i]`, to locate the rows that you are interested in, inside the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
# copying data for manipulation
df1 = df
df1
```

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJO23.png) 
Now that you have a copy of your data, you can locate this data by their indexes at the original dataframe, in this specific case, the Dates that contains "Q".

```
df2 = df.loc[df["Date"].str.contains("Q")]
df2
```

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDmnr.png)
Lastly, you can get indexes from those objects and removing them from the original dataframe, after, that you will get the data that has only de months.
arr_indexes  = df2.index.values.tolist()
df3 = df.drop(arr_indexes);
df3
[df3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVslW.png)